# Setup Laravel Scheduler on AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there some tutorial how to setup cron job on AWS (with Laravel Scheduler)? Simple example would be great, for example how to update (increase by one) MySQL DB column value every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Define your scheduler in schedule method in app/console/kernel.php.
ex:

```
 $schedule->call(function(){
        User::increment('points');
 })->everyMinute();
```

After this, ssh into your ec2, go to /etc and open the file named "crontab", inside that file, paste the following line

```
* * * * * cd <path-to-your-project> && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

That is all. Hope this helps.